# how to get the missing number or days in multidimensional array

Tags: php

how can I get the missing day of Jan and Feb using PHP?
sample array bellow

```
$a = array (
  array("jan",1,2,3,5),
  array("feb",1,2,4,5),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = array (
  array("jan",1,2,3,5),
  array("feb",1,2,4,5),
);

$janDays = $a[0];
$febDays = $a[1];

// get number of days in each month
// cal_days_in_month(calendarType, monthInNumber, currentYear)
$totalJanDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 1, date('Y'));
$totalFebDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, date('Y'));

$janMissingDays = [];
$febMissingDays = [];

// iterate for each day and add numbers not found in array
for ($day = 1; $day <= $totalJanDays; $day++) {
  if (array_search($day, $janDays) === false) {
    $janMissingDays[] = $day;
  }
}

for ($day = 1; $day <= $totalFebDays; $day++) {
  if (array_search($day, $febDays) === false) {
    $febMissingDays[] = $day;
  }
}

// this will hold missing days
print_r($janMissingDays);
print_r($febMissingDays);
?>
```

Comment: @jinxz02 welcome :)